# Hibernate email pattern fails for specified domains

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I am using a `@Pattern` for my `@Email` validation to narrow the email addresses to just three domains and `name.lastname` username. But my code fails and message is displayed every time. What am I doing wrong?

```
@Embeddable
public class Contact
{
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String              firstname;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String              lastname;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    @Pattern.List({ @Pattern(regexp = ".+(@domain1.com|@domain-2.com|@dom-ain-three.com)", message = "Wrong email address") })
    private String              email;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
@Embeddable
public class Contact
{
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String              firstname;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String              lastname;
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    @Email
    @Pattern.List({ @Pattern(regexp = ".+((@domain1\\.com)|(@domain-2\\.com)|(@dom-ain-three\\.com))", message = "Wrong email address") })
    private String              email;
}
```

Escaping the dot characters (meaning any character except new line) fixed the regex.